# Pipe operator (%>%) not working and text in editor not selectable

Tags: r, debugging, pipe, rstudio

I recently had two problems apprearing at the same time in RStudio `2023.3.0.386`:

**1. Pipe operator %>% stopped working with ctrl shift M. (Actually only the source editor is affected, ctrl shift M works in the console).**

**2. Text in the source editor is not selectable by mouse, only by the
keyboard.**

I did not assign the shortcut ctrl shift M to another function. Nor did I install any new software recently.
I checked several sources regarding dfunctive pipe shortcut and I checked all programs that possibly share the same shortkey:

1. https://community.rstudio.com/t/ctrl-shift-m-pipe-operator-shortcut-is-suddenly-stop-working-since-this-morning/118362/14
2. [RStudio pipe operator (%>%) shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+M) not working in Edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479070/rstudio-pipe-operator-shortcut-ctrlshiftm-not-working-in-edge-browser)
3. [Rstudio pipe operator (%>%) shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+M) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69714346/rstudio-pipe-operator-shortcut-ctrlshiftm-not-working)
4. https://defkey.com/what-means/shift-command-m (***this list is very helpful!***)

I also tried to reset the desktop state regarding the non selectable text:

1. https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-select-text-in-rstudio-desktop/37776

I know that I could just change the keyboard shortcut, but I am very, very used to this one.

How could I further debug these two problems?

Comment: For problems/bugs within the RStudio interface, I think opening a new thread on community.rstudio.com is probably the best forum for help.

Comment: Thank you. Should I move it? I thought it would be fine to ask here since a `rstudio` tag exists.

Comment: It is fine to ask here, I just think you'll have more luck there. You can leave it up here just in case and also open a thread there.